# assigning mapped array directly

Tags: ruby

Trying to map stuff I read from a file into a
list of arrays that have an integer and a string

It doesn't seem to to work quite right, because I see 
two strings per array, as opposed to an integer
and a string.

```
list_of_elems = []
File.foreach("line_counts.txt") do |line|
  list_of_elems << arr = line.split(/\s+/).map! { |e, i| i == 0 ? e.to_i : e }
end

list_of_elems.each_with_index do |e, i|
  if i > 10
    break
  end
  p e
end
```

Comment: Could you give a sample line of line_counts.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000250) only passes one argument to the block; hence `i` is always `nil`,  `i == 0` always fails, and `to_i` is never called. I think you want something more like this:

```
list_of_items = File.open('line_counts.txt').collect do |line|
    line.split(/\s+/).inject([ ]) { |a, e| a.push(a.length == 0 ? e.to_i : e) }
end
```

The `a.length == 0` essentially replaces your faulty `i == 0` check and converts the first component of the line to an integer.

If `linecounts.txt` looks like this:

```
1 one
2 two
```

Then `list_of_items` ends up looking like this:

```
[[1, "one"], [2, "two"]]
```

and that seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to take a file like this:

```
test 20 foo
7 1 bar 6
```

And get this:

```
[["test", 20, "foo"],
 [7, 1, "bar", 6]]
```

Right?

Then you can use:

```
list_of_elems = []
File.foreach("line_counts.txt") do |line|
  list_of_elems << line.split(/\s+/).map {|e| e =~ /^(?:+|-)?\d+$/ ? e.to_i : e }
end
```

Or:

```
list_of_elems = File.read("line_counts.txt").split("\n").map do |line|
  line.split(/\s+/).map {|e| e =~ /^(?:+|-)?\d+$/ ? e.to_i : e }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be too relevant, but

```
list_of_elems.each_with_index do |e, i|
  if i > 10
    break
  end
  p e
end
```

can be replaced with

```
list_of_elems[0..10].each {|e| p e}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
list_of_elems = File.foreach("line_counts.txt").map |line|
  line.split.map.with_index { |e, i| i == 0 ? e.to_i : e }
end
```

I use map instead of each for the output because you can hit tab twice in textmate and it builds the block for you.

```
list_of_elems.map { |e| puts e.to_s }
```